# How does 'fc' command works in DOS and how does it work?

Tags: disk-operating-system

DOS had a command `fc`,which was used to compare the files in binary mode, I am a bit stuck with the concept of comparing the files.Why do we compare the files in binary mode? And how does the `fb` command work?

Comment: ERROR  Unbelievable nobody corrected you.  It is FC as in File Compare.  Your question should be what the heck or what specifically, is comparing files in text mode!  Comparing in binary mode should be pretty obvious. It compares the 1s and 0s.. so would see if the file is identical. Text mode might miss out differences involving certain characters, those that are perhaps, non printable non graphical, something like that. If any of them are in the file.

Comment: @barlop: So, by using fb command, we can also compare images. That seems good.

Comment: YES BUT IT IS FC MAN "FILE COMPARE" FC.  Why do you keep typing fb do you use facebook every single second of your life?

Comment: I am really sorry I am a facebook addict.

Comment: Typos happen, don't worry about it. And few users on this site are as rude about it as @barlop. He probably should have [edited](http://superuser.com/privileges/edit) your question himself if he was sure it's a typo.

Comment: @DanielBeck My way, he'll learn to type and remember the command right instead of continuing to miswrite it. Your way, he won't. It is excellent that -he- edited it. I'll +1 him for that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You compare files in binary mode when the files are not text files with well-known end-of-line terminators or line-separators. An example might be some binary data files. In that case you might want to see the offset and hexadecimal values of differences rather than display some before and after versions of text.

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/688504/binary-diff-tool) and [this list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12625/best-diff-tool)